# Why Are My Unit Tests Inconsistently Passing/Failing? (Golang and ScyllaDB)

Tags: database, unit-testing, go, cql, scylla

I'm running into issue with unit tests pertaining to ScyllaDB in Golang. The code doesn't seem to be the problem. The unit tests will sometimes work perfectly, but just as often will also fail. This leads me to believe this could be a database issue, but I'm not sure what it could be. For example, I get back errors like this after creating a new entity `test_server` with some basic entity metadata `description: "desc", owner: "owner"`:

```
Error Trace:    test_file.go:243
                                            test_file.go:68
                Error:          Not equal: 
                                expected: &model.EntityMetadata{state:impl.MessageState{NoUnkeyedLiterals:pragma.NoUnkeyedLiterals{}, DoNotCompare:pragma.DoNotCompare{}, DoNotCopy:pragma.DoNotCopy{}, atomicMessageInfo:(*impl.MessageInfo)(nil)}, sizeCache:0, unknownFields:[]uint8(nil), EntityType:(*string)(0xc000512420), Description:(*string)(0xc000512430), Owner:(*string)(0xc000512440), Features:[]*model.FeatureMetadata(nil), DefaultTtl:(*int64)(0xc00003d1a8)}
                                actual  : &model.EntityMetadata{state:impl.MessageState{NoUnkeyedLiterals:pragma.NoUnkeyedLiterals{}, DoNotCompare:pragma.DoNotCompare{}, DoNotCopy:pragma.DoNotCopy{}, atomicMessageInfo:(*impl.MessageInfo)(nil)}, sizeCache:0, unknownFields:[]uint8(nil), EntityType:(*string)(0xc0005122d0), Description:(*string)(0xc0005122e0), Owner:(*string)(0xc0005122f0), Features:[]*model.FeatureMetadata(nil), DefaultTtl:(*int64)(0xc00003d170)}
                                
                                Diff:
                                --- Expected
                                +++ Actual
                                @@ -13,4 +13,4 @@
                                  EntityType: (*string)((len=11) "test_server"),
                                - Description: (*string)((len=4) "desc"),
                                - Owner: (*string)((len=5) "owner"),
                                + Description: (*string)(""),
                                + Owner: (*string)(""),
                                  Features: ([]*model.FeatureMetadata) <nil>,
                Test:           TestServer/GetEntityList
```

Of course the actual results should appear like this (which I do get sometime):

```
                                    --- Expected
                                    +++ Actual
                                    @@ -13,4 +13,4 @@
                                      EntityType: (*string)((len=11) "test_server"),
                                    - Description: (*string)((len=4) "desc"),
                                    - Owner: (*string)((len=5) "owner"),
                                    + Description: (*string)("desc"),
                                    + Owner: (*string)("owner"),
                                      Features: ([]*model.FeatureMetadata) <nil>,
                    Test:           TestServer/GetEntityList
```

Here is what the unit test looks like (line 68 is where the unit test was called from, a function, and line 243 is where the function lies in the test_file.go lies). Assume that a function earlier has already attempted created this table, with the description and owner:

```
func getEntity(t *testing.T, ctx context.Context, s *Server) {
   res, err := s.GetEntity(ctx, &models.EntityRequest{})
   if assert.NoError(t, err) {
      expected := &models.EntityMetadata{
         EntityType: proto.String("test_server"),
         Description: proto.String("desc"),
         Owner: proto.String("owner"),
   }
   assert.Equal(t, expected, entity)
}
```

I get errors/inconsistencies like these in other unit tests as well, this was just one of them provided. Any help would be appreciated, I've been trying to debug this for a while now.
**Note:** I have an established Read/Write connection for these unit tests, the database is not mocked.

Comment: What does this test test_file.go line 68 do? Is what you refer to as "my unit tests" available somewhere? Where is this "description" and "owner" retrieved from?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the test code, my assumption might be wrong, but:
it seems as you are comparing not the data but *pointers* to data in some cases (at least the output suggests this):

```
EntityType:(*string)(0xc000512420), Description:(*string)(0xc000512430), Owner:(*string)(0xc000512440),
```

Actual:

```
EntityType:(*string)(0xc0005122d0), Description:(*string)(0xc0005122e0),Owner:(*string)(0xc0005122f0)
```

This does not work most of the time; you should compare the actual data values.